# Can you have a space in the object name in JSON string and still retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON object which appears as such:

```
$leo = {"Leonardo DiCaprio":{"ht":"70","wt":"222","eyes":"blue","movie":"titanic"}
```

But I am having a hard time accessing the data. I have tried:

```
var json = JSON.parse($leo);
alert(json.'Leonardo DiCaprio'['movie']);
```

and

```
var json = JSON.parse($leo);
alert(json.['Leonardo DiCaprio']['movie']);
```

and

```
var json = JSON.parse($leo);
var name = 'Leonardo DiCaprio';
alert(json.name['movie']);
```

None have worked for me. But when I remove the space and do alert(json.LeonardoDiCaprio['movie']; I get the movie.

Is there any way to retrieve the data and keep the space?

Comment: You need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` syntax are mutually exclusive but behave the same, in most cases. `foo.['bar']` is not valid.

This is described in [the spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) at [section 12.3.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors):

> Properties are accessed by name, using either the dot notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```
>
> or the bracket notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression [ Expression ]
> CallExpression [ Expression ]
> ```

The `IdentifierName` used in the dot notation must not contain whitespace ([section 11.6](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords)), so you must use the bracket notation in that case.

The exact rules for which Unicode characters are legal are defined in [Unicode TR#31](http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/) and specified in [section 2](http://unicode.org/reports/tr31/#Table_Lexical_Classes_for_Identifiers).

All you need to do here is `json['Leonardo DiCaprio']` and you'll fetch the inner object.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the ending "}" in the JSON String $leo.

-Amit

Comment: This should be a comment on the question. While a helpful note, it doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: It seems I cannot comment yet hence posted as an answer.